# Animate two elements from a vertical alignment to horizontal alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a label directly above a textbox, and this is all centered vertically within the page. After the input is verified I would like to shrink the elements and slide them to the top of the page, while simultaneously "rotating" them to be next to one another, with the label on the left and the textbox on the right. So essentially I want to go from this in the middle of the screen and large:

```
                Label
               Textbox
```

to this at the top of the screen and back to a regular size:

```
           Label: Textbox
```

I just can't seem to figure out the best way to handle it.

*To be clear here, I'm wanting to animate this. To go from the top example to the bottom of the example in fluid motion.*

Here is a fiddle of what I'm beginning with: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/280404/

Here is a fiddle of what I'm wanting to end with: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/280396/

The motion to get from fiddle 1 to fiddle 2 needs to be animated. That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: But how do you animate that?

Comment: Can you provide us a Snippet please ?

Comment: certatly @lance You must be add the snippet

Comment: `But how do you animate that?`. When did you mention animating the element?? You need to show a minimum of effort otherwise we won't help you.

Comment: "After the input is verified I would like to shrink the elements and slide them to the top of the page, while simultaneously 'rotating' them to be next to one another"

I kind of thought that made it clear I was talking about an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I have seen the result you wanted to achieve: smoothly translate the two elements from `inline` to `inline-block`. I've found a way to do this. As it is a completely different approach from my initial solution, I have decided to post another answer.

---

### Setup

You can achieve the desired result with plain CSS but there are a couple of things to take care of.

- we will position the main container `.parent` with `absolute`

  ```
  .parent { 
    position: absolute;

    /* dimensions */
    width:  35%
    height: 20%;

    /* centered horizontally */
    margin: 0 auto; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    /* centered vertically */ 
    bottom: 0; 
    top: 45%; 
  }
  ```
- to change the layout `.parent` will get the class `.parentMod` which will overwrite some of `.parent`'s initial properties:

  ```
  .parentMod {
    top: 10px;
    height: 12%;
  }
  ```
- both sub elements are too positioned with `absolute` their vertical position inside `.parent` have to be set (with percentages to ensure the layout is responsive):

  ```
  .parent > div:nth-child(1) {
    left: calc(50% - 125px);
  }
  .parent > div:nth-child(2) {
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
  ```
- then we can set their position when the layout has changed:

  - both sub elements will have the same vertical position:

    ```
    .parentMod > div:nth-child(1), 
    .parentMod > div:nth-child(2) {
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    ```
  - the second sub element will have a vertical offset (it will be positioned below the first sub element):

    ```
    .parentMod > div:nth-child(2) {
      top: 35px;
    }
    ```

---

### Demo

Overall the result will look like:

```js
const changeLayout = () => {
  document.querySelector('.parent').classList.toggle('parentMod');
};
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 35%;
  height: 20%;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.parent > div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.parent > div:nth-child(1) {
  left: calc(50% - 125px);
}
.parent > div:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.parentMod {
  top: 10px;
  height: 12%;
}
.parentMod > div:nth-child(1), 
.parentMod > div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parentMod > div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Label</div>
  <div>Textbox</div>
</div>

<button onclick="changeLayout()">Switch Layout</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for and I learned quite a bit. Here's my final fiddle for my particular use case. http://jsfiddle.net/b84ycr0t/76/

Comment: I'm glad I could help, nice Fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

### Initial response

1. You can use `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` to vertically and horizontally center your content. In the example: `.parent1`
2. To have both `div` next to each other on the same horizontal level use `display: inline-block`. In the example: `.parent2`

```css
.parent1, .parent2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.parent2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.parent2 > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent2 > div:nth-child(2):before {
  content: ': ';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div>Label</div>
  <div>Textbox</div>
</div>

<br /><hr />

<div class="parent2">
  <div>Label</div>
  <div>Textbox</div>
</div>
```

---

### With animation

**Bonus** if you wish to animate it:

You will need `transition` to set the animation type and duration. Then prepare two CSS classes:

- a default one called `.parent` positionning the item in the center of the screen

  ```
  .parent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: calc(50% - 47px);
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  ```
- another one that will be toggled and which overwriting the position of the element to the top of the screen.

  ```
  .parentMod {
    top: 0px;
  }
  ```

I have added an event listener attached to the button so you can see the animation by toggling the state with a mouse click:

```js
const changeLayout = () => {
  document.querySelector('.parent').classList.toggle('parentMod');
};
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: calc(50% - 47px);
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.parentMod>div {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.parentMod {
  top: 0px;
}

.parentMod>div:nth-child(2):before {
  content: ': ';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Label</div>
  <div>Textbox</div>
</div>

<button onclick="changeLayout()">Switch Layout</button>
```

Comment: Do you know how I could animate the change between those two?

Comment: @Lance Have a look at my edit. Let me know if that's works for you.

Comment: that's pretty close to what I was going for. The only thing is I was hoping to animate everything. Not only the transition from center of page to top, but also the size of the elements and the moving of the label to the left. In my mind I imagine them all transitioning smoothly. But you got it a lot farther than I did so I appreciate that!

Comment: You can set the transition rule to individual CSS properties. The following will make the font size change smoothly: `.parent > div { transition: font-size 2s; }`. If you've found this answer helpful don't forget to upvote/accept it for future reference.

Comment: Is it possible to animate the change to display:inline-block?

Comment: @Lance you can use `transition: all 2s ease` to transition any available property.

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating your suggestions applied to my elements: http://jsfiddle.net/b84ycr0t/28/

My hope was that the movement would be more linear...the label would move straight to it's final resting place rather than up and over, and the same for the textbox. I think to do that I would have to handle this another way, perhaps with absolute positions for each of the two elements and moving them along a straight line. Thanks for your help though, I certainly learned a bit from this.

Comment: I have added a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977383/6331369), it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try positioning them absolutely and using flex-box on the parent to center-align them.

It's not a very flexible solution, but it gets the job done!

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <span id="one">Label</span>
  <span id="two">Textbox</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
#one, #two {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: block;
  height:1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
#one {
  position: absolute;
}
#two {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:1em;
}
.container:hover #one,
.container:hover #two {
  font-size: .75em
}

.container:hover #one{
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.container:hover #two{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left:30px
}
```